# How do I make my index html file a vue app and still be able to host it on firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting

So i've built a vue app with various different pages and a router index page and everything and I was viewing it locally and it looked good and everything was going good but when I went to go host it on firebase I can't figure out how to get my vue app file to show instead of the html one.
You will see that in the HTML the app and the main.js script are in the body of the HTML element.

```
<html>
  <head>
   

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.9.0/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/icon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> Web page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.firestore().doc('/foo/bar').get().then(() => { });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            'auth', 
            'database', 
            'firestore',
            'functions',
            'messaging', 
            'storage', 
            'analytics', 
            'remoteConfig',
            'performance',
          ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });

      
    </script>
  
</html>
```

Aboves the html index file which I originally edited and below is a portion of the App page

```
<div>
    <PopoverButton class="h-8 w-fit text-neutral-400 hover:text-red-800 active:text-red-900 font-bold cursor-pointer inline-flex align-middle p-1 m-4 transition ease-in-out duration-300"
    >Locations</PopoverButton>

    <PopoverPanel class="absolute z-10 bg-neutral-800 rounded-xl">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
        <router-link to="/locations/Sydney">
        <p class="h-8 w-fit m-4 text-neutral-400 hover:text-red-800 active:text-red-900 font-bold cursor-pointer transition ease-in-out duration-300"
        >Sydney</p>
        </router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
```

And below is my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './style/index.css'
import router from '../src/router/index'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'




createApp(App).use(router).use(createPinia()).mount('#app')
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is have it so that the actual vue app and the router-view inside it work again and put the vue app in the body of the index like it did before I hosted on firebase, if anyone has a way to fix this or a better way of doing this please let me know any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you not made a build version with `npm run build`?

Comment: yes I have everything works okay up until the point I move the files and folders into the firebase public folder then it won't read the script src= /src/main.js to get the app mounted anymore.